# Power BI - Automatically identify new folders to get data and combine them

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

A new year is coming and the path where we save our data is changing.

The problem is: the data from each asset is saved in folders with the current year as it's name, so data from 2022 is saved in a folder called 2022, and so on.

I want to make a query that will autamatically indentify what years (folders) we have data from and combine them.

The data is saved in this path:

C:\Users\Projects\3. Assets\Type A\Asset Name\Control\YEAR\Data\Dataset\excel.xlsx

This asset for instance has 3 years of data 2020, 2021 and 2022.

By next week we will already have a 2023 folder with new data, usually a manually add a table.combine to the query, but we have a large number of assets and it can be tricky.

Someone knows a efficient way to automatically identify all the folders named with a year and combine the excel data inside them ?

This is the way i usually do:

```
Table.Combine ({Sharepoint("...2020/Data/Dataset"),Sharepoint("...2021/Data/Dataset"),Sharepoint("...2022/Data/Dataset")})
```

Sharepoint is a function that returns folder content from sharepoint.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you pull all the directory names at a higher level

similar to

https://exceltown.com/en/tutorials/power-bi/powerbi-com-and-power-bi-desktop/power-bi-data-sources/connect-power-query-whole-sharepoint-folder/

then filter them ?

Comment: The data volume is massive for some assets, this way is the most optimal one ?

Comment: Data volume should not matter when you are just pulling directory information and file names. The volume should come later on the expansion once you have properly filtered it.  (Unless there are millions of filenames)

Comment: Ok, i'm going to try this out. Thx